# printf not printing line correctly bash unix

Tags: bash, unix, printf

I am using printf command to log some values in a file as follows:

```
printf "Parameter = $parameter v9_value = $v9_val v9_line = $V9_Line_Count v16_val = $v16_val v16_line = $V16_Line_Count"
```

But the output I am getting as follows:

```
 v16_line = 8elayServerPort v9_value = 41 v9_line = 8 v16_val = 4571
```

Seems like the line is printed in rotation manner, and last values are coming from starting.

Expected Output:

```
Parameter = RelayServerPort v9_value = 41 v9_line = 8 v16_val = 4571 v16_line = 8
```

But `v16_line = 8` is overwritten on `Parameter = R` in line.

Comment: I think some of your variables have carriage returns in them, so the output goes back to the beginning of the line and overwrites it.

Comment: Are you getting these values from a file written on a Windows machine?

Comment: If so, use `dos2unix` to get rid of the CR characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`printf` doesn't add a NL on the end. You need to add `\n` to the end of your `printf`.

Not seeing the rest of your program, or where you get your variable values, it's hard to say what else could be the issue.

One thing you can do is to redirect your output to a file and look at that file either through a good program editor or using `cat -v` which disables control characters.

See if you see `^M` in your output. If you do, it could be that you have `^R` in your variables.

Also remove `$v16_val` from your `printf` (temporarily) and see if your output looks better. If so, that `$v16_val` might have a CR (`^M`) in it.